# Animated View shrink to default position on Tap using PanResponder React Native (version 0.60.5)

Tags: react-native

I want to design a screen like below:-

[image]

The bottom screen (Passage) is vertically swipeable and height will be increased when ever the drag starts .I am able to do that with panresonder, after swiping vertically it will have a full screen height and inside that there will be a scrollview, but when ever I am tapping on this screen when its height is full it is going to shrink in its previous position.

Here is the code i have written:-

```
 componentWillMount() {
        this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
            onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (e, gestureState) => true,

    //When dragging the screen change the height 
            onPanResponderMove: (e, gestureState) => {
                    this.setState({
                        bottomHeight: gestureState.moveY > (this.state.deviceHeight - 40) ? 40 : this.state.deviceHeight - gestureState.moveY,
                    })


            },
// After reaching a certain height when releasing the finger make bottom screen full height.
                onPanResponderRelease: (e, gestureState) => {
                    if (gestureState.dy != 0) {
                        if (gestureState.dy < 0 && Math.abs(gestureState.dy) > 30) {
                            this.setState({
                                bottomHeight: this.state.deviceHeight - 200,
                                collapsed: false,
                                opacity: 0.7,
                                backgroundColor: '#191919'
                            })
                        } else if (gestureState.dy > 10) {
                            this.setState({
                                bottomHeight: 100,
                                collapsed: true,
                                opacity: 1,
                                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
                            })
                        } else {
                            this.setState({
                                bottomHeight: this.state.deviceHeight - 200,
                                collapsed: false,
                                opacity: 0.7,
                                backgroundColor: '#191919'
                            })
                        }
                    }

                }
            });
        }
```

> JSX part

```
<Animated.View
                style={{
                    borderTopWidth: 15,
                    borderTopColor: '#FFD200',
                    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                    position: 'absolute',
                    borderTopLeftRadius: 10,
                    borderTopRightRadius: 10,
                    bottom: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    minHeight: 150,
                    maxHeight: this.state.deviceHeight - 200,
                    height: this.state.bottomHeight
                }}
                {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}
            >



            </Animated.View>
```

I have used [**rn-sliding-up-panel**](https://github.com/octopitus/rn-sliding-up-panel#readme) library but the performance ios not so good when I am dragging the bottom screen, that's why I write it myself.
Is there any way to ignore Tap gesture or any other way to achieve this. I am not so good in animation, a beginner in this, may be this question is silly. Any kind of help is appreciated.